# Operator norm of a matrix less than or equal to one

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Do all matrices of operator norm $\leq 1$ have the sum of the absolute values of their rows $\leq 1$?

Comment: Depends on your norm.

Comment: That depends on which vector norm you're using.

Comment: The vector norm is the usual euclidean norm.

Comment: $A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&1\\-1&1}$.